# Changing the Vibrate settings in Jelly Bean, Android

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, vibration, android-audiomanager

I am looking for how we change the vibrate settings in Jelly Bean. I found that all the pre-JB  vibrate settings have been deprecated, but don't see any new AudioManager.[change the vibrate settings] code anywhere. There is a setting "Vibrate when ringing" which I would like to know how to play with.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In android4.1 you can use this to control "vibrate & ringing"

```
Settings.System.putInt(mContentResolver, Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING, enable ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: Thank you sooo... much! I have searched the whole world wide web for this answer. Thank you!

Comment: This was working like a charm till now, on Android M it throws a IllegalArgumentException: "You cannot change private secure settings."

Answer (score 2):

From the Documentation:

```
This method is deprecated.
Applications should maintain their own vibrate policy based on current ringer mode that can be queried via getRingerMode().
```

Seems like Google wants Vibration settings to be handled by each app for itself on an app to app basis, adjusting it's settings by querying [getRingerMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode%28%29).

Comment: But getRingerMode() will not return the "Vibrate when ringing" setting.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING` is declared with @hide annotation so you may have troubles to use it in Android Studio.
So maybe you have to replace `Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING` by its value : `"vibrate_when_ringing"`

It is annoying that it is declared with the @hide annotation, because it means that Google don't want external developpers using it...

Answer (score 0):

This issue has plagued me for a couple of days now. Finally got it working. Make sure that you have the right permissions as well.

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

}
```

Then in my on click listener I utilized the following:

```
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    if (vibrate == 1) {
                        try {
                            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 1);
                            audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON); //Set it to never vibrate on ring:
                            audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON); //Set it to never vibrate on notify

                            boolean vibrateWhenRinging;
                            vibrateWhenRinging = (Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing") == 1);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Boolean.toString(vibrateWhenRinging), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "System vibrate error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 0);
                            audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF); //Set it to never vibrate on ring:
                            audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF); //Set it to never vibrate on notify

                            boolean vibrateWhenRinging;
                            vibrateWhenRinging = (Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing") == 1);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Boolean.toString(vibrateWhenRinging), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "System vibrate error in else statement", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
```