# Readout vibrate settings from Ringer

Tags: android, vibration

I want to readout the vibrate settings because I temporarily change them and want to set the original settings back again.
Therefore I store the settings like this:

```
vibrate_save = amanager.getVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER));
```

and set it after my change back to the original settings:

```
amanager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, vibrate_save);
```

But after readout, vibrate_save has the value 3 on ICS (only 0,1,2 are possible). On a Android 2.2 it worked. On the explanation I saw "This method is deprecated." But what is the alternativ?

This error cames up:

```
10-07 13:53:58.720: E/AudioManager(6682): wrong value in setVibrateSetting vibrateType:0 vibrateSetting:3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nowbody an idea whats wrong? Is there a different way to read out the vibrate settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that ICS has the vibration settings that earlier versions did.  When I look at the settings on my ICS phone (an HTC), the only option I see is "Vibration feedback for calls and notifications", and all I can do is turn that on or off. On a Samsung device running 2.3, I can set the device to vibrate "always", "never", "only in silent mode", or "only when not in silent mode".  I don't know to what extent the device brands are an issue, but it seems that there just aren't the same settings in ICS. I did find the following, which allows you to control the 1 vibration setting that ICS seems to have: [Changing the Vibrate settings in Jelly Bean, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286116/changing-the-vibrate-settings-in-jelly-bean-android).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 with ICS 4.0.4, there is it possible to adjust the vibration intensity. Is that possible for all ICS devices? If yes, how can I read it an change it?

Comment: I honestly don't know and haven't been able to find anything online. One thing I just tried to do is to change the vibrate settings on my Samsung running 2.3 while it's plugged into my computer, to see what shows up in logcat. As you'd expect, log entries are made when those settings are changed. I don't know how much it would help you, but you might try to do the same with your S2. It is interesting (and perhaps discouraging) that you have different vibration settings on the S2 than I do on my HTC running 4.0.3.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I will take a look on the logcat. But if you dont have this settings on your HTC, then it makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, whatever those settings are on your Samsung, if they're particular to that brand, I assume they're not useful to you. It seems that quite a bit of variation exists between brands as far as software (i.e., skins) is concerned, even with respect to settings that control hardware. I don't know what Samsung does, but I don't think they're just manipulating stuff through the API the way we do.